# SQL Server dynamically sum rows based on other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the situation: I need a way to total sales of a certain class of item every month. Easy enough, right?

Except sometimes, the item will be suppressed (with 0 price) and a special item will be put on the order with the price. I solved this by looking for suppressed lines and using LAG to pull the price from the special item on the line below it:

```
CASE
    WHEN olu.supress_print = 'Y' 
        THEN LAG(shrv.sales_price_home, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY shrv.order_no, pvol.line_seq_no DESC)
        ELSE shrv.sales_price_home
END AS total_sales
```

However, I recently discovered that sometimes they will split the suppressed item into multiple "special" lines. I'm trying to dynamically sum rows of certain trigger items until the row below the trigger item contains a non-special item. I'll illustrate with a table:

| item_id | qty_ordered | tot_price | line_seq | suppress_print |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 150 | 1 | N |
| B | 10 | 0 | 2 | Y |
| SPECIAL | 4 | 140 | 3 | N |
| SPECIAL | 6 | 90 | 4 | N |
| SPECIAL | 8 | 70 | 8 | N |
| SPECIAL | 6 | 80 | 9 | N |

So in this example, I'd like the prices for lines 2, 3, and 4 summed and rolled into one line. I really only need the total price and ideally to be able to preserve item id "B".

I'm trying to think of a way to solve this using exclusively SQL. I know I could write a script to do it, but I'd like to limit this to just SQL if possible.

Edit - unfiltered table (imagine 2 is the item class I want the sum of sales for):

| item_id | qty_ordered | tot_price | line_seq | suppress_print | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 150 | 1 | N | 2 |
| B | 10 | 0 | 2 | Y | 2 |
| SPECIAL | 4 | 140 | 3 | N | NULL |
| SPECIAL | 6 | 90 | 4 | N | NULL |
| C | 5 | 80 | 5 | N | NULL |
| D | 3 | 50 | 6 | N | NULL |
| D | 14 | 0 | 7 | N | NULL |
| SPECIAL | 8 | 70 | 8 | N | NULL |
| SPECIAL | 6 | 80 | 9 | N | NULL |

Edit 2 - expected results:

| item_id | qty_ordered | tot_price | line_seq | suppress_print | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 150 | 1 | N | 2 |
| B | 10 | 230 | 2 | Y | 2 |
| C | 5 | 80 | 5 | N | NULL |
| D | 3 | 50 | 6 | N | NULL |
| D | 14 | 0 | 7 | N | NULL |
| SPECIAL | 8 | 70 | 8 | N | NULL |
| SPECIAL | 6 | 80 | 9 | N | NULL |

Comment: hey i don't understand what do you need exactly , do you want all the special items sum into 1 row ?

Comment: How lthe ine_seq 8 is different (not included) from the line 4 ?

Comment: @Serg line_seq jumps from 4 to 8 because I've already filtered out all the items that aren't either in the class we want to look at or have the ID "SPECIAL". I can include every order line if that would make it easier - I'll edit that in.

Comment: @trillion I want to sum lines 2, 3, and 4. Basically if I were writing a script I'd say starting at line 2, create a running total of "tot_price" until item_id <> "SPECIAL" or Δline_seq > 1

Comment: @D.Rad when you say line 2,3,4 you mean only iteam id A  and B ?

Comment: it is really unclear as to what do you want , can you add another table with expected results and the decription. What do you mean by line 2 ,3 ,4 . What exactly is the line here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something based on your unfiltered table.

I didn't attempt to limit the logic to a specific `class`.
But that could be added easily, at the end, or as needed.

I also didn't really need the `suppress_print` column in the logic.

We could also easily exclude the 'D' items from the `SPECIAL` logic.  Based on the summed qty values and the 0 `tot_price`, I guessed we should treat them specially too.  That's easily adjusted.

We handle this much like an `edges` case, creating groups in the first `groups` CTE term.

Then, in the `sums` CTE term, use these groups to combine / `SUM` the `SPECIAL` rows within their groups / partitions.  The rows associated with non-`SPECIAL` cases are in their own group, so can be summed as well.

The final query expression just takes the `edge` rows, which causes the `SPECIAL` rows to be hidden and the leading `item_id` shown only, as requested.

Here's the SQL Server test case:

[Working Test Case (**Updated**)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12a5452a9a608123418051eac8461fa3)

and the corresponding solution:

```
WITH groups AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , SUM(CASE WHEN item_id <> 'SPECIAL' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY line_seq) AS seq
              , CASE WHEN item_id <> 'SPECIAL' THEN 1 END AS edge
           FROM unfiltered AS t
     )
   , sums AS (
         SELECT item_id,  qty_ordered
              , line_seq, suppress_print, class
              , SUM(tot_price) OVER (PARTITION BY seq) AS tot_price
              , edge
           FROM groups
     )
SELECT item_id,  qty_ordered, tot_price
     , line_seq, suppress_print, class
  FROM sums
 WHERE edge = 1
;
```

Result:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
| item_id | qty_ordered | tot_price | line_seq | suppress_print | class |
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
| A       |          10 |       150 |        1 | N              |     2 |
| B       |          10 |       230 |        2 | Y              |     2 |
| C       |           5 |        80 |        5 | N              |  NULL |
| D       |           3 |        50 |        6 | N              |  NULL |
| D       |          14 |       150 |        7 | N              |  NULL |
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

Both 'B' and the second 'D' item are summed as described in the question description.

The data in the `unfiltered` table:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
| item_id | qty_ordered | tot_price | line_seq | suppress_print | class |
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
| A       |          10 |       150 |        1 | N              |     2 |
| B       |          10 |         0 |        2 | Y              |     2 |
| SPECIAL |           4 |       140 |        3 | N              |  NULL |
| SPECIAL |           6 |        90 |        4 | N              |  NULL |
| C       |           5 |        80 |        5 | N              |  NULL |
| D       |           3 |        50 |        6 | N              |  NULL |
| D       |          14 |         0 |        7 | N              |  NULL |
| SPECIAL |           8 |        70 |        8 | N              |  NULL |
| SPECIAL |           6 |        80 |        9 | N              |  NULL |
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

and the following actually produces the explicit requested result.
I haven't tried to reduce this.  The requirement to restrict the behavior to a specific `class` added work. There were a couple of places I could have re-stated expressions to avoid additional CTE terms.  Feel free to collapse them.

I also regenerated the groups (`seq`) a second time, once the main `class` logic was handled.

```
WITH groups AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , SUM(CASE WHEN item_id <> 'SPECIAL' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY line_seq) AS seq
              , CASE WHEN item_id <> 'SPECIAL' THEN 1 END AS edge
           FROM unfiltered AS t
     )
   , classes AS (
         SELECT item_id,  qty_ordered, tot_price
              , line_seq, suppress_print
              , edge, seq
              , MAX(class) OVER (PARTITION BY seq) AS class
           FROM groups
     )
   , edges AS (
         SELECT item_id,  qty_ordered, tot_price
              , line_seq, suppress_print
              , class
              , CASE WHEN edge = 1 OR class IS NULL THEN 1 END AS edge
              , SUM(CASE WHEN edge = 1 OR class IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY line_seq) AS seq
           FROM classes
     )
   , sums AS (
         SELECT item_id,  qty_ordered
              , line_seq, suppress_print, class
              , SUM(tot_price) OVER (PARTITION BY seq) AS tot_price
              , edge
           FROM edges
     )
SELECT item_id,  qty_ordered, tot_price
     , line_seq, suppress_print, class
  FROM sums
 WHERE edge = 1
;
```

Result:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
| item_id | qty_ordered | tot_price | line_seq | suppress_print | class |
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
| A       |          10 |       150 |        1 | N              |     2 |
| B       |          10 |       230 |        2 | Y              |     2 |
| C       |           5 |        80 |        5 | N              |  NULL |
| D       |           3 |        50 |        6 | N              |  NULL |
| D       |          14 |         0 |        7 | N              |  NULL |
| SPECIAL |           8 |        70 |        8 | N              |  NULL |
| SPECIAL |           6 |        80 |        9 | N              |  NULL |
+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `APPLY` to get parent info for 'SPECIAL's of item with `suppress_print` = 'Y'

```
WITH grp AS (
  SELECT  -- all but tot_price from parent
     coalesce(parent.item_id, itm.item_id) item_id,
     coalesce(parent.qty_ordered, itm.qty_ordered) qty_ordered,
     itm.tot_price,
     coalesce(parent.line_seq, itm.line_seq) line_seq,
     coalesce(parent.suppress_print, itm.suppress_print) suppress_print, 
     coalesce(parent.class, itm.class) class
  FROM myTbl itm
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT t3.* 
    FROM (
       SELECT top(1) t2.*
       FROM myTbl t2 
       WHERE itm.item_id = 'SPECIAL' AND t2.line_seq < itm.line_seq AND t2.item_id != 'SPECIAL' 
       ORDER BY line_seq DESC 
    ) t3
    WHERE t3.suppress_print = 'Y'
  ) parent
)
select item_id, qty_ordered, sum(tot_price) tot_price, line_seq, suppress_print, class
from grp
group by item_id, qty_ordered, line_seq, suppress_print, class
order by line_seq
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer simply because it came in sooner, but this works just as well. Thank you, I really appreciate it!